# Как убрать значение из инпута?

Tags: django

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот это не placeholder, а сам текст, который юзеру приходиться убирать. Как его убрать?

Comment: если укаажешь место в html как ты выводишь этот инпут(и описание формы, если ты выводишь его с помощью форм), можно будет дать конкретный совет

Answer (score 0):

Я с Django не работал, но судя по первой ссылке в выдаче Google, вам нужно указать пустой label: `label=''`. Подробнее на [англоязычном stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25839043/how-do-i-remove-label-text-in-django-generated-form).